# Script / Shortcut to switch display priority?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I wish to have a shortcut which switches the priority (i.e. primary, secondary) of the displays (laptop + external).

PS: I am aware that there's a dedicated button/shortcut to do this but, at least mine, cycles through all configurations (i.e. different resolutions). I want to cycle between two configurations only.

Comment: why? there should be one on your keyboard. probably Fn F8

Comment: @Rinzwind Actually I have two but they cycle through all possible configurations (with different resolutions).

Comment: What is exactly the purpose? A screen being primary does not mean that much on Ubuntu, mostly for launcher presence, if set to only on primary. The order is set separately.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I am using Ubuntu Gnome so switching the priority changes the location of the top bar, launcher & dash.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Absolutely. Can wait.  All the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out I already wrote it, as part of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/711479/72216). Since it is *another question*, below an outtake of that one:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

# Look up the currently set primary screen, set it to the other one
scr_data = subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()
scrs = [[l.split()[0], "primary" in l] for l in scr_data if " connected" in l]
for screen in scrs:
    if not screen[1]:
        subprocess.Popen(["xrandr", "--output", screen[0], "--primary"])
```

It toggles (switches between the two) the primary screen.

#### To use:

- copy the script into an empty file, save it as `toggle_primary.py`
- Add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

  ```
    python3 /path/to/toggle_primary.py
  ```

Comment: @user10853 you're welcom! Glad to help :)

Comment: +1 because this script and shortcut hotkey feels very similar to what I'd like to do (toggle between 2 resolutions). @JacobVlijm I'd really love your thoughts at https://askubuntu.com/q/1378237/48214